# Is $(() => {}) an jQuery anonymous or ready function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

This is the first time seeing this. I have looked this up and have not found anything pertaining to this syntax of $(()).

```
<script>
    'use strict';
    $(() => {
        // code goes here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which bit are you confused about? The syntax for the anonymous function itself, or its use in jquery ready?

Comment: I am confused about what it is entirely. It looks similar to both an anonymous and ready function in jQuery at the same time. I have not seen this before. I do not understand how or why this would be used versus the more common jQuery practices: http://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, for the most part, the equivalent of:

```
<script>
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        // code goes here
    });
</script>
```

Which, assuming the `$` variable is assigned to the jQuery library, will be a "normal" document ready callback function.

You can learn more about arrow functions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: So I guess the lack of the function keyword was throwing me off. I have not found any documentation discussing this type of usage.

Comment: To be clear, Arrow functions are NOT jQuery-specific, so you may not see anything in the jQuery documentation about them.  Arrow functions are a new syntax for anonymous functions in JavaScript.

Comment: More precisely, this is the equivalent of `$(function () { ... }.bind(this))`. jQuery is infamous for using *dislexical* `this`.